# How to map field name to another name in Ag Grid for React?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have col def like the following. In AG Grid, we do sort this filed. But we pass sort request to backend to query DB and send back sort result to AG GRid.

Since we have some legacy code, UI need to map the field: "stockStatus" to another name called stockStatusSort. the request payload will look like this
{
property: stockStatusSort;
direction: ASC

}

COL_STOCK_STATUS: {
headerName: "Status",
field: "stockStatus",

}

I am not sure if AG Col Def can have some function like:

COL_STOCK_STATUS: {
headerName: "Status",
field: "stockStatus",
map :  stockStatusSort
}

So When I click sort arrow. the UI will send the mapped payload to backend

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ag-grid does not support that directly, but you can implement a "value getter" function, and configure that in the column definition.

Then the function can supply the value with whatever logic you care to write.

See the documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters